# How to change delegate to NSURLSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, delegates, nsurlsession

I am using `NSURLSession` for server communication. I am having 2 class individually for Downloading and uploading files. I want to use Single `NSURLSession` for downloading and uploading operation. In such I can't change the delegate for `NSURLSession` at run time by using `setDelegate` option, since I'm using Delegates to validate data. Is there any way to change delegate object for NSURLSession at run time?

Thanks.

Comment: what you can do is introduce a third delegate and call its methods from both the classes whenever their URLSessionDelegate delegate method gets called.

Comment: Use of `Singleton` can help

Comment: "I want to use Single NSURLSession for downloading and uploading operation" Why? Needing different delegates is exactly why you would use multiple NSURLSessions.

Comment: @matt : I want to restrict number of connection to host, that will be easy if you are using single NSURLSession. That's the reason to use single Session. I would like to do single upload or download at time.

Answer (score 2):

The `delegate` cannot be changed. It is the delegate that was "assigned when this object was created." And as [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlsession/1411530-delegate?language=objc) goes on to say:

> **Note:**
>
> This `delegate` object must be set at object creation time and may not be changed.

So, you'll have to design a delegate object that can differentiate between your various network tasks, handling each appropriately.

You could, theoretically, create separate delegate objects, and maintain a dictionary, keyed by the task identifier, of pointers to secondary delegate objects. You can then write a delegate for the `NSURLSession` that, for the task delegate methods, looked up the task identifier in its dictionary, calling the appropriate method in the appropriate delegate object. But this is a bit inelegant, so you should probably stop and ask yourself if there are simpler ways to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As Rob says, you can't change the delegate of an NSURLSession.

You have a few other options.

- You can set up a download manager object (probably a singleton) that
  manages the NSURLSession and is it's delegate, and have it forward
  messages to whatever object requested the upload or download.
- You can create multiple instances of NSURSession, one for uploading
  and one for downloading, each with a separate delegate. (You said you
  don't want to do that, but you should revisit that option.
- You can use the `NSURLSession` methods that pass a completion handler
  rather than using a delegate..